# Lynda.com - Building an online portfolio on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

It works on the video, as they told, I created a file called posttypes.php into the theme folder containing this code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello!";
?>
```

I have made a file called functions.php put into the child theme cooking:

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp_content/themes/posttypes.php');
?>
```

As a consequence, I should have visually outputten a Hello! This is not the case, I have the following error output:

> Warning:
>   include_once(C:\wamp\www\portfolio/wp_content/themes/posttypes.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\portfolio\wp-content\themes\cooking\functions.php on line
>   2'

and

> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'C:\wamp\www\portfolio/wp_content/themes/posttypes.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\portfolio\wp-content\themes\cooking\functions.php on line
>   2

What did I fail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the tutorial you're following but it looks like you missed the theme folder.

```
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp_content/themes/THEME-FOLDER/posttypes.php');
```